# Is it possible to configure a Cisco router to serve as a Teredo relay?

Tags: cisco, ipv6, ios, teredo

The router in question is a Cisco 871, show version as follows:

```
Cisco IOS Software, C870 Software (C870-ADVIPSERVICESK9-M), Version 12.4(24)T8,
RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport
Copyright (c) 1986-2012 by Cisco Systems, Inc.
Compiled Sun 09-Sep-12 09:09 by prod_rel_team
```

If so, what would a sample configuration for this scenario look like?  And would there be any particular problems in running it on a router which is already providing IPv6 to its "internal" network via a 6ot4 tunnel?

Comment: Don't bother with Teredo. It's a very unreliable technology that is likely to go away in the future in favour of native IPv6 connectivity or more stable transition technology like SixXS or Hurricane Electric tunnels.

Comment: @SanderSteffann Unfortunately, for now I don't have anything else to use (that I'm aware of) to connect back from a mobile device which can be behind arbitrary not-mine-to-control not-ICMPable-or-passing-protocol-41 NATs.  I'd use an HE tunnel if I could. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: No.

Teredo is common on Windows PC as a work-around for the lack of a local ipv6 router.

ftp://ftp.rfc-editor.org/in-notes/rfc4380.txt details the protocol and operation.

Cisco has support for 6to4 auto-tunnels and 6rd, but alas no Teredo support.

More client info at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teredo_tunneling#Implementations

Comment: That applies as a relay, as well as as a client?  The router has native IPv6 as well as IPv4 - I just want it to act as a relay for a remote Teredo client.